# synthetic event error is occured when trying to access form data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, events

i have the following code in my component of react

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function CreateArea() {
  var [items,setitems]=useState({title:{},content:""});

  function updatef(event){
    console.log(event);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input name="title" onChange={updatef} placeholder="Title" />
        <textarea name="content" onChange={updatef} placeholder="Take a note..." rows="3" />
        <button>Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateArea;
```

As you can see i am trying to trigger updatef function if user is typing in the input box and textarea but i am getting the following warning

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If
> you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a
> released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must
> keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().

also my event.target is coming as null
I want to access the input and text area values and store them but event.target is being set to null

any help?

Comment: Please check this https://medium.com/trabe/react-syntheticevent-reuse-889cd52981b6

Comment: i used the event.persist() and then it is working fine but sometimes i recall i did not use this persist () method in the past and it still worked any reason for that? and also do we need to use this event.persist() each time trying to access a form data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to declare an arrow function as your handler:

```
<input name="title" onChange={e => updatef(e)} placeholder="Title" />
<textarea name="content" onChange={e => updatef(e)} placeholder="Take a note..." rows="3" />
```

Comment: thank you this method also works too can you specify the reason this works? what are we doing here passing e?

Answer (score 1):

The below code will help you out, use the `event.persist()`, that will remove the synthetic event error

```js
onChange={(event) => {
  event.persist();
  setState((preValue) => {
    return { ...preValue, input: e.target.value };
  });
}}
```